# OpenId with Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, openid

What are your solutions?

Has anyone successfully implemented OpenId with a Silverlight 2 app?

OpenId requires a redirect to an outside site. I was looking forward to a slick Silverlighty login page for my app, but this isn't going to happen by the looks of things!

Comment: Don't use 'dotnet' for a tag - use '.net' instead. Please pay attention the suggest prompts when tagging your question - any tag with a number < 10 after the name should probably be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an interesting problem.  The SL2 app must not verify the OpenID assertion itself but rather pass it off to the server to verify it.  The SL2 app *could* verify it, but then the nonce is consumed and the server couldn't re-verify it, but ultimately the server MUST verify it to be secure.  So most likely login should occur before the SL2 app even appears, and then it can appear with a logged in context already there.

There are probably other ways to do it, but the above restriction of the server being the verifier of the assertion is clear.